# Tree of lambda functions in Java?

Tags: java, lambda

I am porting some software and it's working in Swift and JavaScript, but I cannot figure out how to do it in Java.

The JavaScript version looks like:

```
var obj = { "A": {
      "1": (params) => { console.log("A1", params); },  
      "2": (params) => { console.log("A2", params); }
    }, // A
    "B": {
      "1": (params) => { console.log("B1", params); },  
      "2": (params) => { console.log("B2", params);}
     }, //B
}; // obj
```

Where at runtime, the application engine calls

```
var a = 'A'; 
var i = '2';
obj[a][i](params);
```

I for the life of me cannot figure out how to do this in Java. One key constraint (no pun intended) is that the code must be structurally similar to the other ports.

Previously, I was trying to use Object[][], with

```
Map<String, Object> map = Stream.of(obj).collect(Collectors.toMap(data -> (String) data[0], data -> (Object) data[1]));
```

to be able to embed some Map<String, Integer> objects. Example:

```
Map<String, Integer> colorMap = Stream.of(new Object[][] {
        {"black", 0x000000},
        {"navy", 0x000080},
};
```

I tried to arrive at similar code, but Java did not like it, because lambdas and Object are not compatible.

The code I am looking to arrive at is:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Callable<Void> > > obj =  Stream.of(new Object[][] {
  {"A", Stream.of(new Object[][] {
    {"1", (params)->{ System.out.println("A1"); } },
    {"2", (params)->{ System.out.println("A2"); } } }),
  {"B", Stream.of(new Object[][] {
    {"1", (params)->{ System.out.println("B1"); } },
    {"2", (params)->{ System.out.println("B2"); } } } )}
  } 
});
...
// call the function (assuming A and 1 exist)
obj.get("A").get("1")(params);
```

But I am stumped on how to convert this to being able to use lambdas. The error I keep getting is:
`error: incompatible types: Object is not a functional interface`
or `error: lambda expression not expected here`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible structure-preserving translation to Java is:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Runnable>> obj = Map.of(
    "A", Map.of(
        "1", () -> System.out.println("A1"),
        "2", () -> System.out.println("A2")
    ),
    "B", Map.of(
        "1", () -> System.out.println("B1"),
        "2", () -> System.out.println("B2")
    )
);
```

You use it like this:

```
obj.get("A").get("2").run();
```

If you need to pass arguments, or return values from the functions, replace `Runnable` with a different functional interface. You may have to defined one of your own. For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface FunctionWithObjectParameters {
    void run(Object... args);
}
```

---

**Update:** If you need to do this in Java 8, one option is to use an external library that has methods to construct maps in a more convenient way - like [guava collect](https://github.com/google/guava).

Another option is to implement the convenience methods yourself. `Map.of` does not do any magic, you can easily replace it with your own "mapOf" method:

```
static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapOf(K key1, V value1) {
    return mapOfEntries(entry(key1, value1));
}

static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapOf(K key1, V value1, K key2, V value2) {
    return mapOfEntries(entry(key1, value1), entry(key2, value2));
}

static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapOf(K key1, V value1, K key2, V value2, K key3, V value3) {
    return mapOfEntries(entry(key1, value1), entry(key2, value2), entry(key3, value3));
}

// Add  more overloads if you need

static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapOfEntries(Map.Entry<K, V>... args) {
    // On Android, you may want to use ArrayMap instead of HashMap
    Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> arg : args) {
        map.put(arg.getKey(), arg.getValue());
    }
    return map;
}

static <K, V> Map.Entry<K, V> entry(K key, V value) {
    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value);
}
```

Comment: So this works wonderfully for Java 9, but I'm stuck on Java 8 it seems (Android). Is there a way to modify this to work with 8?

Comment: Updated the answer @UserOneFourTwo

Comment: Hrm... This is looking less like the the overall solution. If have 26 entries in the top-level map, and 4 in each sub-map. This means I would need a mapOf that takes op to 52 parameters?

Comment: Yes, it would mean that. The standard library `Map.of` has the same problem: you can pass in at most 10 key-value pairs. The alternative is to use `mapOfEntries` directly which does not have the limitation but forces you to use a different syntax: must wrap each key-value pair in a function call

Comment: What would that mapOfEntries look like?

Comment: mapOfEntries is a function defined in my answer, and there are three examples of how it's used.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that initially this starts out fast, but as I add entries, the compilation slows down exponentially. With 36 top-level entries, it takes ~4.5 minutes to compile.